# Google Sheets Script Help Request: Copy check boxed rows from multiple sheets to new sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

> **Full disclosure**: I have zero programming experience, but I'm a quick study.

I am trying to be able to copy individual rows from a number of different sheets to be copied to one specific sheet. I spent some time looking at previous questions/answers on this (great) site, and I was able to piece together a script that seems to do PART of what I'm looking for.

I can see where in the script I could/should change to get the functionality I'm looking for -- BUT I don't know what to put in the code to actually do what I'm hoping to do. I come to this community humbly asking for help/guidance.

Here's the script that I pieced together and [a link to the example I've been working with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MH_T6fK6X87D7JSqCmv4J75piSks6fj1vX7Nno7yXvA/edit?usp=sharing):

```
function onEdit(event) {
 // assumes source data in sheet named ABC
 // target sheet of copy to named Interdisciplinary
 // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 15 or O
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
 var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

 if(s.getName() == "ABC" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == true) {
   var row = r.getRow();
   var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Interdisciplinary");
   var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
   s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Interdisciplinary" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == false) {
 }
}
```

I know that I'm identifying a specific sheet to pull data from (ABC), what might I put there to pull from any sheet where a checkbox has been clicked?

I also know that I'm having the rows copied to a row that is some defined place away from the LastRow. What might I be able to put there to have the row copied either a row w/in my semester headings OR to have the copied to the top of the new sheet?

Finally, I'd truly appreciate any other comments, feedback, guidance that the community might have for my request.

Thanks much!
Kd

Comment: Can you provide the sample result you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically, the results I'm hoping to get (in the Interdisciplinary tab) would just be a list of rows coming from Checkbox clicked rows from all other sheets. Best case scenario, those copied rows would populate in the Interdisciplinary tab under the corresponding semester, but getting them to that tab via clickbox would be good, too...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your time. One more question:.
I had hoped to be able to have the same functionality on my other tabs (not just the one named ABC). I know that I've specifically put both:

// assumes source data in sheet named ABC
and
if (s.getName() == "ABC"

I only put that because I found that from a similar request for help. Is there a way to be able to have rows from each of the sheets/tabs copied to the *Interdisciplinary* tab via checkbox? I know it'll replace the code I've typed above, but I'm just not sure what commands/code would work...
I appreciate your time/help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. The problem is that the code in your spreadsheet is looking at column 21, not column 15.

Also, I suggest that you review the properties available to you in the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit). You should use them instead of the first three declarations you wrote. You can see the change in my version below.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheets =  ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"]; // Sheet names that will trigger execution. Case-sensitive.

  // target sheet of copy to named Interdisciplinary
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 15 or O
  var ss = event.source;
  var s = event.range.getSheet();
  var r = event.range;

  if (sheets.indexOf(s.getName()) != -1 && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Interdisciplinary");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Interdisciplinary" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == false) {

  }
}
```

EDIT: I've modified the code to show you how to allow triggering from multiple sheets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help. I updated declarations to match what you shared.
I had hoped to be able to have the same functionality on my other tabs(not just the one named ABC). I know that I've specifically put both:

// assumes source data in sheet named ABC
and
if (s.getName() == "ABC"

I only put that because I found that from a similar request for help. Is there a way to be able to have rows from each of the sheets/tabs copied to the Interdisciplinary tab via checkbox? I know it'll replace the code I've typed above, but I'm just not sure what commands/code would work...

Comment: @Kevinbeijing Please check this answer and let me know if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/58830273/1329498

Comment: ![ImageofCode](https://i.imgur.com/vKExAiI.png)
Thank you again for replying to my post. The answer you linked to did provide some help, but --as I'm really not sure what I'm doing -- I am unable to go beyond setting up the array of all possible sheets *I think I've done that* but I'm not sure then how to put it in my: "if" statement. Again, my goal is that by clicking on a checkbox in any of my sheets, I'd love for that row to be copied to the last sheet, called Interdisciplinary.

Comment: @Kevinbeijing I updated the code in my answer. The condition you're missing is `sheets.indexOf(s.getName()) != -1`. That checks if the sheet name exists in the `sheets` array. If this answers your question, please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Final issue *about to give up and have a student worker just manually do it for me*
For the ABC sheet *where it does seem to be working* I'm getting duplicate rows being copied over to my Interdisciplinary sheet. (ie: if i click row 4 in ABC, two of that row will then be copied to Interdisciplinary sheet). Last question - promise!

Comment: @Kevinbeijing Please look at your project triggers. Do you have one that calls the `onEdit()` function? If so, please delete it. You should not need to create a trigger for `onEdit()` because Google automatically knows what to do with it–the name is special.